# How much diskspace do I need for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage

I intend to get myself a new mini-pc with a single SSD. How much diskpace will Ubuntu 14.04 need? 
Is it recommendable to get two seperate disks?

I have following models in mind:

- Shuttle XS35V4
- Shuttle XS36V4

Comment: The default install will work in as little as 10 GB. Any more is up to what you plan to do with it.

Comment: What is the most recommended set up? All on one plate or data on another disk?

Comment: @empedokles there is no recommended setup. The installtion nowadays takes in consideration that there can be a /home present under / or as a sep. part. The only thing to consider might be the wear of the SSD: I would save documents not on disk but on an USB to lower the writes to the SSD.

Comment: @Rinzwind: My idea was to store docs on the SSD because of the speed gain. Unfortunately there is only one USB3 and I'm not sure if I could use it for an external drive.

Comment: @Rinzwind What is the fastest cheap brand for SSD? (120GB or 240GB).

Comment: Official minimum is 5GB for Desktop - https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch03s04.html

Comment: @empedokles OCZ is good and cheap(ish). And the 3 I have have not let me down yes.

Comment: @Evo Basic is the cheapest here. Unfortunately the write speed of the 120GB model is less than that of the 240GB model.

Comment: @Rinzwind Are you keeping your /tmp off of the SSD?  I tried running it in ram for a bit but stopped (I'm using HDD)

Comment: Nope. I have my system in my ssd (and also have a 2nd ssd in spare ;) ) All my files are on external.

Comment: @Rinzwind Over USB 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 GB space is fine enough for installation

Comment: But this doesn't include any space for additional software or personal data. @ErkanMDR please include that in your answer.

Comment: @the_Seppi personal data does not need to be included: you can save those on an USB or on-line. Additional software is rather subjective (what anyone wants is up to the individual); The default covers a lot of ground so might be enough for most of us in this case. Deleting libreoffice (and just use gedit for text) for instance saves up a lot if extra needed. No I consider 8 GB a good answer. More is better ok but 8 GB is useable.